# How to use ~~satya~~ (strike) in pagedown js?

Tags: javascript, markdown, pagedown

**I'm using like below code**

```js
$('#convert').click(function(){
var message = $('#textarea').val();
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
var output = converter.makeHtml(message);
console.log(output);      
$('#show').html(output);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="textarea"></textarea><br>
<input type="button" name="" value="submit" id="convert">
<div id="show"></div>
```

**But ~~satya~~ was not working**
How to make strike through work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown does not include support for strike-through in its syntax. Some implementations have added support as a non-standard addon, but the syntax varies across those (few) implementations. Without checking their docs, I do not know if pagedown offers such support, but I would assume not. In fact that would be my assumption for any Markdown implementation.

That said, the [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. ...
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

Therefore, the following Markdown:

```
<del>satya</del>
```

will result in the following rendered document:

> <del>satya</del>